# difficulty using pip to install bz2file

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I'm trying to use pip to install the bz2file wheel for Windows, but encountering the following error.  Does anyone know how I can proceed?

```
c:\Python35-32>python -m pip install Lib\site-packages\bz2file-0.98-py2.py3-none-any.whl.url
Invalid requirement: 'Lib\site-packages\bz2file\u20110.98\u2011py2.py3\u2011none\u2011any.whl.url'
It looks like a path. Does it exist ?
```

Comment: Why does the name of the wheel end with `.url` instead of `.whl`?

Comment: @jwodder that is a very good question -- I think that's how it downloaded from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ which is where I get wheels for windows.  I'm trying to re-download it

Comment: @jwodder I somehow ended up with a shortcut to the file instead of the file itself in my site-packages directory.  Fixed that and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

@jwodder pointed out that my wheel name ended in `.whl.url` rather than just `.whl` -- this apparently happened because I somehow created a shortcut in my site-packages directory instead of moving the file there. Correcting this fixed the problem.